# getting full url to named route from inside model class Laravel5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-routing

I want to generate the full url to one of my named routes from inside a model class. I am trying this:

```
//file: thread.php
public function getPathAttribute()
{
    return route('threads.show',['thread'=>$this->id]);
}
```

Problem is it is generating a url string that starts with **http://localhost/**
but not with my domain **myforum.com**.

If i am doing the same thing from inside any of my blade views, i get the correct url, i.e; **myforum.com/threads/11**

How do i get this to work from my model?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `.env` file by changing the value of your variable `APP_URL` to `myforum.com`